# "Twilio Quest" challenge, any help would be appreciated, I dont know what I'm doing wrong,

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, object, twilio

## Can't seem to get a hang of this "Twilio Quest" Challenge.

Hey, I've been playing this game called "Twilio Quest" for the past week. 
I just wanted to learn JavaScript, and I think it looked kinda neat. 
The challenges served has been up and down in difficulty. But I've always managed to get around, until now. 
Been reading through: [JavaScript.info - Classes](https://javascript.info/class), [MDN - Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes), [JavaScript.info - Object literal notation](https://javascript.info/object#literals-and-properties) and [MDN - Object Initialization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) I tried alot of aproaches. But I really can't seem to get a hang of this challenge. 

 Heres what I'm trying to do:

```
class TargetingSolution {
  constructor(config) {
    // your code here
  }

  // your code here
}

// The following lines of code are not required for the solution, but can be
// used by you to test your solution.
const m = new TargetingSolution({
  x: 10,
  y: 15,
  z: 900
});

console.log(m.target()); // would print "(10, 15, 900)"
```

Comment: Isn't this just a matter of saving the config into properties of the object, and then defining a `target()` method that returns the formatted string? This seems like basic stuff tbh.

Comment: It probably is, but I'm new to all of this. Thanks for awnsering.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
class TargetingSolution {
  constructor(config) {
    this.value = `(${config.x}, ${config.y}, ${config.z})`
    this.target = () => this.value;
  }
}

let m = new TargetingSolution({
  x: 10,
  y: 15,
  z: 900
});

console.log(m.target());
```

Comment: Strictly speaking this works, but it's pretty damn obvious that `TargetingSolution` will be expanded to do more stuff, and so just discarding `config` after the constructor is run is not helpful.

Comment: No problem @user3569947, look into js anonymous functions and js template literals. As for what Niet said, if that is true I'm sorry lol I thought it was just 1 specific question!

Answer (score 0):

```
class TargetingSolution{
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    z = 0;
    constructor(config){
        this.x = config.x;
        this.y = config.y;
        this.z = config.z;
    }
    target(){
        return '('+this.x+', '+this.y+', '+this.z+')';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class TargetingSolution {
constructor (object) {
this.xcoord= String(object.x)
this.ycoord = String(object.y)
this.zcoord = String(object.z)
}
target() {
return ('('+this.xcoord+', '+this.ycoord+', '+this.zcoord+')')
}}
const sln = new TargetingSolution ({
X: 45,
y: 12,
z: -1
})
console.log(sln.target())
```